# How do I make the model classes in my library reusable for Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data

If I was to create a reusable iOS library how would I create the model objects so that they are useable with Core Data i.e. model objects that inherit from NSObject or NSManagedObject?

At very least I know that I won't be able to override isEqual: and hash since NSManagedObject uses them.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way is to let the Core Data management features in Xcode create your model classes for you, then add extra methods to those generated classes as necessary. For example, if you had a model class 'Thing', you might:

1. Create a Core Data model with the Thing entity and all its appropriate attributes
2. Select the Thing entity and choose Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass
3. Save the file; you'll get a new Thing.h and Thing.m in your project
4. Edit those classes as normal, being careful not to override any of [these methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001171-SW4)

Comment: So I guess all the classes that utilize my model classes should check if my models implement protocols specific to my library instead of being the member of a class?

Comment: That's a more general API design problem, and you can address it in several ways. You could only expose non-Core Data classes and just use Core Data completely internally; you could document that you use Core Data and forbid overriding the same set of methods Apple does; or you could do something else entirely. It really depends on the interface you intend to expose and the desired uses for your library.

Comment: (Or you could do your protocol thing, or provide delegates on all the relevant objects in your library, or...)